# Inserting into two tables not working. Is there a proper way?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Having trouble trying to get this code to work. Maybe I was going in the wrong direction but I essentially am inserting some data into one table like password username and type, while the other table will have customer information.

```
   connection.connect(function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + error.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

ex.get("/create-user", function(req, res, next)  {
//use err or error?
connection.beginTransaction(function(error){
  if (error) {throw error;}
  connection.query('Insert into users( user_name, user_password, user_type) values (?,?,?)', [req.query.userName, req.query.password, req.query.Customer=1], function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log(req.query);
    if (error) {
      connection.rollback(function(){
        throw error;
      });      
    }

      connection.query('Insert into customers(cust_first_name, cust_last_name, cust_email, cust_city, cust_address, cust_zip_code, cust_state, cust_phone_num, cust_role, cust_website, cust_business_name) values (?,?,?)', [req.query.custFirstName, req.query.custLastName, req.query.custEmail, req.query.custCity, req.query.custAddress, req.query.custZipcode, req.query.custState, req.query.custPhone, req.query.custRole, req.query.custWebsite], [req.query.userName, req.query.password, req.query.Customer=1], function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error) {
        connection.rollback(function(){
          throw error;
        });
      }
      connection.commit(function(error){
          if (error) {
            connection.rollback(function(){
              throw error;
            });
          }
          console.log('transaction complete');
          connection.end();
        });
      });
    res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
    });
  });
});
var server = http.createServer(ex);
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing some question marks in your second insert, have you tried the customer insert alone? When debugging try to separate your code into individual concerns and test them individually

Comment: @wizebin I able to do the first insert alone without the beginTransaction function and the second query but adding either of those it ends up not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
connection.query('Insert into customers(cust_first_name, cust_last_name, cust_email, 
  cust_city, cust_address, cust_zip_code, cust_state, cust_phone_num, cust_role, 
  cust_website, cust_business_name) 
values (?,?,?)', 
[req.query.custFirstName, req.query.custLastName, req.query.custEmail, 
 req.query.custCity, req.query.custAddress, req.query.custZipcode,  
 req.query.custState, req.query.custPhone, req.query.custRole, 
 req.query.custWebsite], 
[req.query.userName, req.query.password, req.query.Customer=1],
```

This specifies 11 columns, but you only have three `?` placeholders.

Then you pass 10 values in the next argument. You need 11.

And you inexplicably pass an extra set of three values, which look like a copy & paste from the earlier INSERT.

You need to have exactly one `?` for each column in the INSERT, and then pass exactly one value for each `?`.

You might find this alternative syntax for INSERT to be more intuitive:

```
Insert into customers set cust_first_name=?, cust_last_name=?, cust_email=?,
   cust_city=?, cust_address=?, cust_zip_code=?, cust_state=?, cust_phone_num=?, 
   cust_role=?, cust_website=?, cust_business_name=?
```

That's a MySQL custom syntax (won't work in other brands of SQL), but it makes it a lot easier to match up the number of `?` placeholders with the number of columns.

Comment: I will give it a try and no surprisingly it was not a copy and paste but a brain fart.Update: so i node like before I get this error (forgot to put this in the op) I get:`throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^
TypeError: this._callback.apply is not a function`

Comment: Embarrassing. I see my issue. I was an extra couple values from the previous insert. Now Im getting a syntax error.